# Memory Access Errors for member variables (WinDbg)

Tags: windbg

I'm trying to watch member variables of a c++ class while debugging in WinDbg. I set my breakpoint in a member function and I'm observing the variables while I step one line after next. However, I keep getting this Memory Access Error for all the member variables. Is there any way to resolve this? I need this to debug my code.

Thanks,

Amay

Comment: Do you get the same errors if you debugged using visual studio?

Comment: I did not try with Visual Studio. I have the code running onto a device and Windbg is attached to that device. So, when I'm inside the member function and stepping through, I type dt -r this. This is what I get:

   +0x00c notifier         : ???? 
   +0x010 clnt             : ????

These are the member variables of my class object. At the end, it shows Memory read error 000000ee

Comment: What does `? this` or `dv this` show? Maybe your this pointer is invalid.

Comment: ?this shows Evaluate expression: 16447824 = 00faf950 and dv this shows this = 0xfffffffe.. 
When I make the object, it's memory location is 00faf958 not 00faf950a and subsequently for all the member variables, the memory location is different as compared to the memory location of the object. When I do dv "original memory location" in the member function, I can read the contents. However, the question is, why windbg changes the memory locations of the member variables when I'm inside the member function

Comment: it might be easier to post the output of above commands.

Answer (score 1):

Are you debugging a release or a debug version? In case of a release version, the this pointer will be stored in the ecx register. That register might be reused for different purposes throughout your method. You can verify that by pressing the 'locations' button in your locals window. If that is the problem, try setting a breakpoint in the very beginning of your method, and verify the contents of the ecx register. Then use that value as a watch, for example:
(CMyClass*)*address in ecx*

Make sure you specify the address in the 0x format, which is one of the peculiarities of windbg.